Prevent Dictionary from being transformed to KeyValuePair when used as IEnumerable.Zip extention parameter
Replacing my first invalid question with this brief reproducible example
var firstObjects = new List<object>();
var secondObjects = new List<object>();
Dictionary<object, object> inner = secondObjects.Select(o => o).Zip(secondObjects).ToDictionary();
var outer = firstObjects.Select(o => o).Zip(inner).ToDictionary();

The question is why is the result of outer:
Dictionary<object, KeyValuePair<object, object>>
rather than:
Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, object>>

can you show exmple of data from characteristics  call and service  data exmaple ? how can i recreate your example?

just substitute characteristics with an object and remove the await, its not important to the example.  sorry i will update the question.

What do expect Zip to do? What is characteristics? What is Services? Can you please provide a [mre]?

@GuruStron  question corrected/updated

@PowerMouse question corrected/updated

@GuruStronGur Zip is an IEnumerable extension method of the framework

@axa "Zip is an IEnumerable extension method of the framework" - yes, I know that =) That is not what I asked. What is the expected/desired result here? You want to add the same Dictionary<object, object> to every item from firstObjects?

@GuruStron Zip is transforming the Dictionary into a KeyValuePair, i expected it not to

@axa Zip accepts two collections and merges them based on index, so it is an expected behavior here.

"Zip is transforming the Dictionary into a KeyValuePair" - no, Zip is iterating over the dictionary where each item is a KeyValuePair. Is your expected result a dictionary where the value is the entire dictionary or a dictionary with one entry?  Could you add some sample data and what you expect as a result?

you need something like this .ToDictionary(k=>((JObject)k).Properties().First().GUID, v=> v.Values().First().Value());

I'm really unclear what you expect it to do. What do you want here, and why? Please show a [mcve] with expected results.

@Charlieface you can reference Guru Stron answer for What was wanted here.  Why was simply because i wanted to know


The question is why is the result of outer: Dictionary<object, KeyValuePair<object, object>> rather than: Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, object>>

Basically the same why result of the inner is Dictionary<object, object>.
Enumerable.Zip<TFirst,TSecond>(IEnumerable<TFirst>, IEnumerable<TSecond>) as the docs state:

Produces a sequence of tuples with elements from the two specified sequences.


Returns
IEnumerable<ValueTuple<TFirst, TSecond>>
A sequence of tuples with elements taken from the first and second sequences, in that order.

And Dictionary<TKey, TValue> is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> (docs), so the result is pretty much expected.
If you want the result of the Zip to be IEnumerable<object, Dictionary<...>> you need to zip with collection of dictionaries, i.e. something like:
IEnumerable<Dictionary<object, object>> dicts = ...;
var outer = firstObjects.Select(o => o)
   .Zip(dicts)
   .ToDictionary();

Note that potentially you might want Select, not Zip here but without actual code/sample data and desired result it's hard to tell.
